# Заполнение двумерного массива, находящегося в структуре строками

Tags: c, struct, malloc, calloc

Есть структура, заполненная двумерными массивами

```
typedef struct
{
    char** f;
    char** s;
    char** t;
    char** f4;
    char** f5;
} RICK;
```

Из мейна я передаю в функцию указатель на структуру и пытаюсь заполнить элементы строками (Мне нужны массивы строк)

```
int size = max_size(text), current_size = 0; // max_size выясняет количество байт файла.
    char* size_test = (char*)malloc(size);

while ((fscanf(text, "%c", &check[0])) == 1)
    {
        if (check[0] == '^' || check[0] == '#')
        {
            ...
        }
        else
        {
            fseek(text, -1, SEEK_CUR);
            current_size = strlen(fgets(size_test, size, text));
            heyho->f5[idx_secf5++] = (char*)calloc(current_size, 1);
            heyho->f5[idx_secf5 - 1] = size_test; 
        }
    }
```

По какой-то причине в итоге получаю, что все элементы массива f5 на выходе равны последнему считанному значению, хотя, вроде как, указатели на элементы должны отличаться, индексы же разные. Спасибо!

Comment: Вы же сами **сразу** указатель меняете на одно и то-же. `heyho->f5[idx_secf5 - 1] = size_test;` `size_test` - одинаково везде.

Comment: 1) Потому что эта строка `heyho->f5[idx_secf5 - 1] = size_test;` не копирует содержимое строки, на которую указывает указатель `size_test` в память, на которую указывает указатель `f5[idx_secf5 - 1]`, а просто перезавписывает указатель в `f5[idx_secf5 - 1]`.  Т.е. указатель на ранее выделенную память `calloc(current_size, 1)` безвозвратно теряется.  Используйте функцию `strcpy()`: `strcpy(heyho->f5[idx_secf5 - 1], size_test)`. 2) Здесь `calloc(current_size, 1)` не хватает одного байта для завершающего нулевого символа в конце строки. 3)Проверьте не забыли ли нулевые символы в других местах.

Comment: @wololo, спасибо!

Comment: @AlexGlebe, Спасибо!